# with sbt higher than 1.5.8 Akka server stops immediately after running

Tags: scala, sbt, akka-http

I had, from my point of view, a stable version of the application,
but when I update sbt from 1.5.8 to 1.6.X or 1.7.X or 1.8.X or 1.9.0 (latest)
I found that AkkaHttpServer stops immediately after the run. (just exit from command run if starting the application from sbt and just exit from sbt completely if starting from command line with the command 'sbt run')

higher than 1.5.8:

```
sbt:event-calendar-scala> run
[info] running com.------.Application 
12:47:27.125 [EventCalendarServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
SLF4J: A number (1) of logging calls during the initialization phase have been intercepted and are
SLF4J: now being replayed. These are subject to the filtering rules of the underlying logging system.
SLF4J: See also https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#replay
12:47:27.842 [EventCalendarServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed 22 Jun 2023, 12:47:28
12:47:28.241 [EventCalendarServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO  akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem - Server online at http://0.0.0.0:8080/ for docker or http://127.0.0.1:8080
sbt:event-calendar-scala>
```

sbt 1.5.8

```
    sbt:event-calendar-scala> run
[info] running com.-------.Application 
13:13:13.093 [EventCalendarServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
SLF4J: A number (1) of logging calls during the initialization phase have been intercepted and are
SLF4J: now being replayed. These are subject to the filtering rules of the underlying logging system.
SLF4J: See also https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#replay
13:13:13.481 [EventCalendarServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
13:13:13.730 [EventCalendarServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO  akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem - Server online at http://0.0.0.0:8080/ for docker or http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

Here I use:

val AkkaVersion = "2.6.20" //apache 2.0 license

val AkkaHttpVersion = "10.2.10" //apache 2.0 license